# Document Converstion for PDF form (eg. w2/1040/etc) as key/values instead of a single string based on font information

Tags: ibm-watson, document-conversion

Trying to use the Document Conversion service to capture the json key/value pairs for the pdf documents such as (w2/1040/etc forms.)

Content of such forms in json response are coming as part of the "text" under the "content". Missing the form data, but mostly rendering the form labels as a single string.

I would like to know if there is anyway to capture the form data for the pdf (w2/1040/etc) as key / values in json instead of a single string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Document Conversion Service currently does not support forms in PDFs. At most, it may recognize some of the forms as tables, but not as key/value pairs.

If it recognizes a form as a table, you still would need to do some non-trivial post-processing to map it to key/value pairs.